# How can I copy multiple files from inventory_hostname in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to log my config files, using `inventory_hostname` variable but it's only considering the first host in my inventory file and copying its config to all the other hosts. (Note: All 3 configs are different)

My Task:

```yaml
- name: Logging Output
  blockinfile:
    path: "./output.log"
    block: |
      Config files
      ------------------------------
      {% for host_name in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
      {{ host_name }}
      {{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg
      {% endfor %}
```

My inventory file:

```
[junos]
junos-1
junos-2
junos-3

[junos:vars]
ansible_network_os=junos
ansible_connection=netconf
```

My config files:

```
junos-1.cfg
junos-2.cfg
junos-3.cfg
```

which were created using:

```
- name: Generate Config
  template:
    src: ./generate_config.j2
    dest: ./{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg
```

Can someone please suggest how can I copy all my configs for their respective hosts or if there is a way I can loop within `inventory_hostname` in the same task to fetch my configs?

Comment: Just run the exact same template task (again...) but `delegate_to: localhost` and you get the same content on your controller (if I correctly got what you are trying to do). Your logging task can't work anyway as lookup only runs on controller and your templated filles are remote

Comment: @Zeitounator: But in case of "delegate_to: localhost` then the output is overwritten, when the playbook runs against more then one external host (parallel execution)

Comment: Did you try? (Obviously not...) Unless you have several hosts having the same `inventory_hostname` which is not possible.

Comment: If you need to get on track: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/42f0a5ac71707519bf9736a84f0b690d